# How can I prevent objects from falling into the gap behind my freestanding range?

Tags: kitchen-counters, stove, gap, glass-top-range

We just had a new freestanding electric range installed at our house this morning. My wife called me after it was installed and told me that the new power cord plug is thicker than our old one, causing a gap of 2 to 3 inches between the range and the wall. This post on another forum [has photos of a similar situation](http://ths.gardenweb.com/forums/load/kitchbath/msg11120817895.html?29).

We keep several small items on the counter right by the range. We are worried they may get knocked into the gap. Is anyone aware of a way to prevent objects from falling into this gap?

Comment: Product and service questions are off topic, so I edited the question to keep in on topic.

Comment: Most range manufactures sell filler strips that fill that space behind the range.  Big box home improvement stores might even have them.  You could do an internet search for "range rear filler strip" and see what pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there are two options, though it sounds like you just replaced the range and haven't made any other changes, so you might only have one.

If its the plug sticking out that is the issue, then either yourself or an electrician (depending on your skill level) can change out the outlet for a recessed outlet. Whether you can do this will depend on a lot of things, like what is behind or in the wall.

The other option that is more common when installing new counters is to cut a thin piece of the counter top to go behind the stove. You would also need to support the piece, and again, the type of material will dictate how much support is needed; laminate is a lot lighter than granite, for example.